# jQuery invoke function only when ajax of the previous function was executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I have the following problem:

```
$('#id').on('click', '.class', function(){
 // it is doing something and
 // executing AJAX request
 // with the data from request it is doing something
} // this is onclick handler
```

Later in the code I need to execute it as well and after executing I need to run another function which depends on the ajax execution of this `onclick handler`, so I am doing something like this

```
$('#id .class').click();
anotherFunction();
```

It is not working. The problem is understandable, because the ajax request has not finished.

I tried to achieve the right execution using the idea of [Deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

```
$.when( $('#id .class').click() ).then( anotherFunction() );
```

And using the idea of autoexecuted functions with callback:

```
(function(o, callback){
    $('#id .class').click()
})(null, anotherFunction() );
```

Both ideas failed.

Is there any way to achieve the intended functionality without modifying `anotherFunction()` and `onclick function`?

Comment: `.click` is just shorthand for `.on('click'` . Please specify - you want to call a second function after the first function process the response?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I entirely understand your question, but what keeps you from executing your onsuccess / onerror code in the corresponding $.ajax response methods?

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "your url",
  data: "your data",
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { ... },
  success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { ... }
});
```

Also, why don't you put the ajax executing part to an own function and call it from the event handler and on every other place, like this?

```
function ajaxMe(onerror, onsuccess)
{
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "your url",
      data: "your data",
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { onerror(...) },
      success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { onsuccess(...) }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... Just call `anotherFunction` in `.done(function(o){})`